# Why is $\frac{-125}{-8} = \frac{1}{r^{3}}$ equate to $\frac{8}{125} = r^{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am writing exponential functions and I have reached this: $\frac{-125}{-8} = \frac{1}{r^{3}}$

I tried to get an answer but got it wrong, so I opened all the hints and it came to this part of the equation, but then it simplified it as:

$\frac{8}{125} = r^{3}$; I don't understand this; what happened to the $1$? I would assume it got multiplied, but then how did $\frac{-125}{-8}$ turn into frac{8}{125}? I understand that two negatives make a positive, but why is it now the reciprocal of $\frac{-125}{-8}$? I didn't even know that the reciprocal rule applied here.

Comment: $$\frac{-125}{-8}=\frac{125}{8}=\frac{1}{\frac{8}{125}}=\frac{1}{r^3}$$

This is equivalent to $\frac{8}{125}=r^3$.

Comment: If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$, then just flipping the fractions, it's also true that $\frac{b}{a} = \frac dc$ (assuming none of these numbers are $0$).

Comment: thanks @Bye_World - but, could you give an example of this?? I don't just want to know little tricks; rather, I would like to understand it :)

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen Example: $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{4}$ implies $\frac 21 = 2 = \frac 42$.  The idea: If you have two numbers $x,y$ and a function $f$.  Then if $x=y$, we know that $f(x)$ must equal $f(y)$.  Now take $f(x) = (x)^{-1}$ (which is the function that turns nonzero numbers into their reciprocals).  Then we get $x=y \implies f(x) = f(y) \implies (x)^{-1} = (y)^{-1}$ which just says that if you have two nonzero numbers that are equal, then their reciprocals must also be equal.

Comment: Thanks a gazillion, @Bye_World!!!

Comment: I don't know whether you're understanding or not so I'll try to explain a little more. If $x=y$ then $x$ and $y$ are the *same number*. For instance $1+1=2$ says that the number $1+1$ and the number $2$ *are exactly the same*. Then if we apply the same function to each that will *change* the numbers, but it'll change them in the same way.  So when I find the reciprocal of $x$ and the reciprocal of $y$, I will almost certainly get different #s than $x$ or $y$.  But they will still be the same # *as each other* b/c $x$ and $y$ are really just **two different names for the same number**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate the reciprocal of both sides of the equation, you obtain the result.
$$
\frac{-125}{-8} = \frac{1}{r^3}
$$
$$
\frac{-8}{-125} = \frac{r^3}{1}
$$
$$
\frac{8}{125} = r^3
$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{-125}{-8}=\frac{125}{8}$$ and thus we get $$\frac{125r^3}{8}=1$$ multiplying by $$\frac{8}{125}$$ we obtain $$r^3=\frac{8}{125}$$